# Oracle RADIUS authentication requiring to re-authenticate for every query

Tags: oracle, authentication

My company has switched the Oracle authentication from a password to RADIUS authentication. The only change I needed to make in Oracle SQL Developer was oracle.net.authentication_services = RADIUS. I am able to login and work fine. But when I use another application, like Intellij IDEA, I am having issues. I set the authentication service to RADIUS and am able to connect. However each time I want to run a query, I need to enter my passcode. Is there some way to keep the connection alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it is nature if application you use. It opens a new connection for each query. Try execute this multiple time

```
  select distinct sid from v$mystat;
```

To check whether session/connection ID changes each time.